# PostgreSQL Update with date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have this statement that works, but it's unbridled, as in it SUMs up the whole column, I want introduce date range but I'm getting an error.

HERE IS WHAT IS WORKING

```
UPDATE payroll_employee e
    SET hours = l.total
FROM (SELECT employee, SUM(end_date - start_date) AS total
    FROM payroll_timelog
    GROUP BY employee) l
WHERE e.id = l.employee
```

I want to introduce a date filter.
Then I tried this CTE,

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT employee_id, end_date SUM(end_date - start_date) AS total
    FROM payroll_timelog
    WHERE employee_id = 1, AND end_date > 2020-09-01
)
UPDATE payroll_employee e
   SET hours = total
FROM cte
WHERE e.id = 1;
```

Tried casting date to 2020-09-01::date, 2020-09-01::timestamp etc, still won't work. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean "won't work"? Add input parameters and expected result.

Comment: You have a comma before the `AND` so the query won't parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have syntax errors:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT employee_id, SUM(end_date - start_date) AS total
      FROM payroll_timelog
      WHERE employee_id = 1 AND end_date > '2020-09-01'
      GROUP BY employee_id
)
UPDATE payroll_employee e
   SET hours = cte.total
FROM cte
WHERE e.id = 1;
```

Comment: Got :  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 2:       SELECT employee_id, end_date SUM(end_date - start_date...